# FullCalendar Lightning Component Issue - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'moment.fn')

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm implementing a Lightning Component with FullCalendar.io

I'm using FullCalendar 2.7.1 
- https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v2.7.1

My static resources are

- jQuery: jquery.min.js (v2.1.4)
- FullCalendarJS: fullcalendar.js (v2.7.1)
- FullCalendarCSS: fullcalendar.css (v2.7.1)

**Error**

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'moment.fn') throws at https://org-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/c/calendarHarness.app:1043:28
```

**calendarHarness.App**

```
<aura:application >
  <c:fullCalendar />
</aura:application>
```

**fullCalendar.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="FullCalendarController" implements="force:appHostable">
  <ltng:require scripts="/resource/1484095596000/jQuery,/resource/1484095745000/FullCalendarJS" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}"/>
  <ltng:require styles="/resource/1484095772000/FullCalendarCSS"/>
  <aura:attribute name="events" type="Booking__c[]" />
  <div id="calendar"></div>
</aura:component>
```

**fullCalendarController.js**

```
({
  afterScriptsLoaded: function(cmp,evt,helper){
    var events = cmp.get("v.events");
    console.log(events);
    if(!events.length)
    {
        helper.fetchEvents(cmp);
    }
  }
})
```

**fullCalendarHelper.js**

```
({
loadDataToCalendar :function(component,data){      
    var ele = component.find('calendar').getElement();
        $(ele).fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2016-04-01',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            events:data
    });
},

tranformToFullCalendarFormat : function(component,events) {
    var eventArr = [];
    for(var i = 0;i < events.length;i++){
        eventArr.push({
            'id':events[i].Id,
            'start':events[i].StartDateTime,
            'end':events[i].EndDateTime,
            'title':events[i].Subject
        });
    }
    return eventArr;
},

fetchEvents : function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.getEvents"); 
    var self = this;
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
            var eventArr = self.tranformToFullCalendarFormat(component,response.getReturnValue());
            self.loadDataToCalendar(component,eventArr);
            component.set("v.events",eventArr);
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
} 
})
```

**fullCalendarController.apxc**

```
public class FullCalendarController {
  @AuraEnabled
  public static List<Booking__c> getEvents(){
    return [SELECT ID,Name,Event_Start__c,Event_End__c FROM Booking__c];
  }
}
```

----- **Update** ----- 
**fullCalendar.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="FullCalendarController" implements="force:appHostable">
  <ltng:require
    styles="{!$Resource.FullCalendarCSS + '/fullcalendar.css'}"
    scripts="{!join(',', 
      $Resource.FullCalendarJS + '/fullcalendar.js', 
      $Resource.jQuery + '/jquery.min.js',
      $Resource.MomentJS + '/moment.min.js')}"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}"/>
  <aura:attribute name="events" type="Booking__c[]" />
  <div id="calendar"></div>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to avoid any external dependencies (moment.js).

However if you can't avoid it, you will need to include the moment.js script in your lightning require call. Also, I'm pretty sure that you need to append all your requires together into one.

Here is how to use lightning require:

```
<ltng:require
    scripts="{!join(',', 
    $Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibOne.js', 
    $Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibTwo.js')}"/>
```

Reference [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ltng_require.htm)

Comment: Hey Caspar, I'm creating an actual calendar component to hold and display events that are existing records in a custom object. Not a calendar picker.

Comment: Oh. My bad. I'll delete most of the answer. However, the top part is still right. You need to include moment and just use one require.

Comment: I made an update to my question (at the bottom) to show the updated fullCalendar.cmp, is this the correct formatting for requires?

Comment: For anyone curious how the require code looks like in practice, see this thread: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155711/how-to-properly-load-static-resources-in-lightning-components/155712#155712